# Неопределенная функция plugin_dir_path и add_filter

Tags: php, wordpress

Почему пишет, что функция неопределена, как можно исправить?

```
<?php


/*
Plugin Name: cenzorship
Description: цензурирование
Version: 1.0
Author: Rumeone
*/

define('CENZORSHIP_DIR',  plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ));

function cenzorship_filter_the_content($the_content) {
    static $badwords = array();
    if(empty($badwords)) {
        $badwords = explode(',', file_get_contents(CENZORSHIP_DIR . 'badwords.txt'));
    }

    for ( $i = 0, $c = count($badwords); $i < $c; $i++) {
        $the_content = preg_replace('#'.$badwords[$i].'#iu', '{плохое слово}', $the_content );
    }

    return $the_content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'cenzorship_filter_the_content');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В настройках PhpStorm в секции php надо указать framework WordPress.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Указал путь к проекту на wordpress, но все равно ошибки остались

Comment: Ищите, что вы сделали неправильно. То, что я написал - работает.

Comment: Добавил картинку.

Comment: Обновил фотографию в вопросе, показал как установлен wordpress

Comment: И отлично - на последней картинке шторма видно, что функции уже НЕ подчёркнуты.

Comment: Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.